# I cannot login after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've published my ASP application on my local machin using IIS10.
when I try to login or register a new user after deployment I got this error

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are >pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending >model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set >DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable >automatic migration.

I use visual studio 2013, Entityframework 6.1.3,Windows Authentication

Answer (score 5):

You need to run `Update-Database` against your target database.

Open the package manager console window and select your Entity Framework project, then type that command. As long as the config is pointing to the correct DB, it should update it.

```
PM> Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
PM>
```

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. I've tried to update the database but I got this error There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database._